# Test with Easymock for cases testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I'm currently working on unit testing, and I'm trying to create a test testing different cases for a single function. For example, I have the following function:

```
public static String foo(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
    String returnValue = null;
    if(arg0.getName() != null && arg0.getId() != null) {
        returnValue = "Value 1";
    } else if (arg1.getName() != null && arg1.getId() != null ) {
        returnValue = "Value 2";
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I want to test the following cases :

- Case 1: `arg0.getName() == null` and `arg1.getName() == null`
- Case 2: `arg0.getName() != null` and `arg0.getId() != null` and `arg1.getName() == null`
- Case 3: `arg0.getName() == null` and `arg1.getName() != null` and `arg1.getId() != null`

etc...

My current test looks like this :

```
public void testFoo() {
    /** Setting up my mocks**/
    Obj arg0 = createMock(Obj.class);
    Obj arg1 = createMock(Obj.class);

    /** Setting my mocks behaviors **/

    // Case 1
    EasyMock.expect(arg0.getName()).andReturn(null);
    EasyMock.expect(arg1.getName()).andReturn(null);

    // Case 2
    EasyMock.expect(arg0.getName()).andReturn("Jack");
    EasyMock.expect(arg0.getId()).andReturn(1);
    EasyMock.expect(arg1.getName()).andReturn(null);

    // Case 3
    EasyMock.expect(arg0.getName()).andReturn(null);
    EasyMock.expect(arg1.getName()).andReturn("Paul");
    EasyMock.expect(arg1.getId()).andReturn(2);

    //End Cases
    EasyMock.replay(arg0_case1, arg0_case2, arg0_case3,
```

arg1_case1, arg1_case2, arg1_case3);

```
    /** Testing **/

    // Case 1
    String expectedValue = null;
    String output = foo(arg0, arg1);
    assertEquals(expectedValue, output);

    // Case 2
    expectedValue = "Value 1";
    output = foo(arg0, arg1);
    assertEquals(expectedValue, output);

    // Case 3
    expectedValue = "Value 2";
    output = foo(arg0, arg1);
    assertEquals(expectedValue, output);
}
```

The issue I have with this test is that even if I set up my mocks for each test case, it seems that the set up fails to follow the order I choosed. I tried to add a `.once()`, `atLeastOnce()`, but even with that, it fails.

Do you have any solutions for this kind of test ? Maybe I should write a different test for each case ?

---

**EDIT**
I found a solution, thanks to @swayamraina's solution and some modification on my code. It's not the most efficient answer, but it does the job. Here's my edited code :

```
public void testFoo() {
/** Setting my mocks behaviors **/

// Case 1
Obj arg0_case1 = createMock(Obj.class);
Obj arg1_case1 = createMock(Obj.class);
EasyMock.expect(arg0_case1.getName()).andReturn(null).anyTimes();
EasyMock.expect(arg1_case1.getName()).andReturn(null).anyTimes();

// Case 2
Obj arg0_case2 = createMock(Obj.class);
Obj arg1_case2 = createMock(Obj.class);
EasyMock.expect(arg0_case2.getName()).andReturn("Jack").anyTimes();
EasyMock.expect(arg0_case2.getId()).andReturn(1).anyTimes();
EasyMock.expect(arg1_case2.getName()).andReturn(null).anyTimes();

// Case 3
Obj arg0_case3 = createMock(Obj.class);
Obj arg1_case3 = createMock(Obj.class);
EasyMock.expect(arg0_case3.getName()).andReturn(null).anyTimes();
EasyMock.expect(arg1_case3.getName()).andReturn("Paul").anyTimes();
EasyMock.expect(arg1_case3.getId()).andReturn(2).anyTimes();

//End Cases
EasyMock.replay(arg0, arg1);

/** Testing **/

// Case 1
String expectedValue = null;
String output = foo(arg0_case1, arg1_case1);
assertEquals(expectedValue, output);

// Case 2
expectedValue = "Value 1";
output = foo(arg0_case2, arg1_case2);
assertEquals(expectedValue, output);

// Case 3
expectedValue = "Value 2";
output = foo(arg0_case3, arg1_case3);
assertEquals(expectedValue, output);
```

Like @swayamraina proposed in its answer, I created different mocks for each case test, and I add a `.anyTimes()` after each `EasyMock.expect().andReturn()`, and it works well.
I'll keep this post update on improvements I may implement.

Comment: Absolutely create one unit test method per test scenario. Since you have 3 cases, at minimum, you would have 3 test methods (one test per case) at minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I have 60 functions to test, and at least 8 cases to test each time. The function in the post is a pure example, and I would like to keep my test class as lisible and simple as possible. Is this the only solution ?

Comment: Think of unit tests as your safety net. We rarely need 100% test coverage of our code, but we need enough to show our code works as we intend. Only you can say how much safety net is enough to keep your project from going splat.

Comment: No need to create different objects everytime. You can reuse the objects and replace them with different values. Refer my solution.

Comment: Beyond that, just to be really sure: you really **need** to mock these objects? You can't do a `new A()` in your test code, add the required data, and pass those objects to your code under test?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this specific case, I need to mock these objects indeed. The code I wrote here is just an example, but in my real test, the objects I need are linked to a database, so mocking them is mandatory because if I create them, my code create automatically new datas in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below is the updated test case**

```
@Test
public void test()  {

  A arg0, arg1;

  // Case 1
  arg0 = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
  arg1 = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);

  // expectations
  EasyMock.expect(arg0.getName()).andReturn(null).once();
  EasyMock.expect(arg1.getName()).andReturn(null).once();
  EasyMock.replay(arg0, arg1);

  // actuals
  String expectedValue = null;
  String output = foo(arg0, arg1);

  // assertions
  Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, output);


  // Case 2
  arg0 = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
  arg1 = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);

  // expectations
  EasyMock.expect(arg0.getName()).andReturn("Jack").once();
  EasyMock.expect(arg0.getId()).andReturn(1).once();
  EasyMock.expect(arg1.getName()).andReturn(null).once();
  EasyMock.replay(arg0, arg1);

  // actuals
  expectedValue = "Value 1";
  output = foo(arg0, arg1);

  // assertions
  Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, output);


  // Case 3
  arg0 = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
  arg1 = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);

  // expectations
  EasyMock.expect(arg0.getName()).andReturn(null).once();
  EasyMock.expect(arg1.getName()).andReturn("Paul").once();
  EasyMock.expect(arg1.getId()).andReturn(2).once();
  EasyMock.replay(arg0, arg1);

  // actuals
  expectedValue = "Value 2";
  output = foo(arg0, arg1);

  // assertions
  Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, output);
}
```

**Test class used:**

```
class A {
    String name; public String getName() {return  name;} 
    Integer id; public Integer getId(){return id;}
}
```

**Notes:** 
You can only replay the mocks only once. You need to create new test objects for every test case. Here, we are first creating mocks then setting expectations and replaying the mocks. Finally asserting against the actual values.

As a general process, I like to create 1 test function per unit (actual function) with . multiple test cases describing each.

Also each test case follows the below pattern

1. declare variables
2. describe test case
3. set expectations
4. define result (actual)
5. apply assertions

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try with this structure, and I'll tell you if it works for me ;)

Comment: Sure, Happy to help. Please do mark the answer as accepted for others who face similar problem in future and land on this question.

Comment: I tried this structure this morning, it's not working : I tried with two cases, and for some reason, the first case passes, but the second one doesn't. I tried the deleting the .once() on the EasyMock.expect().andReturn(), but it seems the case 2 fails because of the second call of my foo() function. I'm working on it

Comment: The code that i have posted is working fine in my environment.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried it, and it works fine only if I add .anyTimes() after every expect().andReturn(). I edited my post. Thanks again for your help !

Comment: @ZoulouDu94 no need to create objects like 'arg0_case3' you can reuse the 'arg0' variable.

Comment: @swayamaraina for some unknown reasons, if I reuse arg0 in the other tests, i get an error ''Unexpected method call expected: 1, actual: 2 java.lang.AssertionError" for the methods getName() and getId(). I'm still working on improving my current test code, but for instance the only way i found to make my test work is to create objects _caseX for each test case